# Controlling Output Format when Sending Output to different Notebook

Tags: notebooks, output-formatting

I want to use Mathematica to generate reports, containing tables, plots and (a bit of) text.
Now plots and text, I've got pretty much figured out, but I'm sort of stuck at tables.
For plots, I've read that if you want to output of a plot, you need to use ToBoxes. I've tried the same with tables and to some degree, this works as well.
e.g.

```
nb = CreateDocument[]`
NotebookWrite[nb,ToBoxes@TableForm[{1,2}]]
```

does what I want it to do (basically a 1 and 2).

However, if the numbers get more complicated, I start seeing issues.
e.g. when using real numbers:

```
nb = CreateDocument[]
NotebookWrite[nb,ToBoxes@TableForm[{RandomReal[],RandomReal[]}]]
```

In this case, the output is not the same as what I would see in the main notebook.
e.g. the first number in the main notebook would be printed as `0.241549`
but in the notebook it is written to as `0.24154997589498572` (with a tailing backtick).

It gets even worse if trying to use a specific formatting, like EngineeringForm:

```
nb = CreateDocument[]
NotebookWrite[nb,ToBoxes@EngineeringForm@TableForm[{RandomReal[], RandomReal[]}]]
```

In this case, the result is formatted into strings and the strings are shown with quotes, so basically in InputForm?

So basically, the question is: how can I write a Table in proper OutputForm to another notebook.
Or do I have to write the expression and then evaluate it?

Comment: Use `NotebookWrite[nb, Cell[BoxData[boxes], "Output"]]` where boxes is the output of your `ToBoxes` call.

Comment: Thanks, that works. :)